# How Adaboost calculates error for each weak learner in training?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, ensemble-modeling, adaboost

I am studying the Adaboost classification algorithm because i would like to implement it from scratch. I understand how it works, but i am not able to understand where some steps are placed.

I will describe the Adaboost training steps in my understanding (sorry for any incorrect formalism):

- Initialize a weak learner $k$
- Define a weight for each sample in the dataset equally $w =\frac{1}{N}$
- Fit $k$ to the dataset
- Calculate error $e = \sum_{i=0}^{N}e_iw_i$
- Calculate importance $\alpha$ of $k$, i.e. $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}log(\frac{1-e}{e})$
- Recalculate weights for the correct classified samples: $w_{t+1} = w  e^{\alpha}$
- Recalculate weights for the incorrect classified samples: $w_{t+1} = w  e^{-\alpha}$
- Normalize new sample weights: $w_{normalized} = \frac{w}{\sum_{i=0}^N w_i}$
- For all sequent learners, select samples based in weighted random choice until get a dataset with same size as the original and do the same proccess.

My question is: how error is obtained? Regarding the implementation, should i firstly fit the dataset and then get the error from predicting the same dataset? This doesn't seems correct.

I've tried to read different sources about this and even a great explanation from the Statquest channel wasn't able to make this clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I started learning about ensemble methods, [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix6IvwbVpw0&t=928s&ab_channel=AlexanderIhler) help me greatly.

The idea is that you fit the model on the data, calculate the error and then work with the error. So yes you should use a weak learner to predict your data and then, use another weak learner.

There are some more videos in the same channel that give a great explanation to have an intuition.

Comment: Oh ok, so this "error" is calculated by first: fitting the model to the data and using the same data to predict? Thanks for the video recommendation!

Comment: Yes, i reccomend  you to see the Boosting video, it helped me greatly when coding from scratch

Comment: Sure, i will take a look at the video and then come back here to check your answer :D